# Find the general term for the recursive sequence $ x_{n+1} = 3 x_n + n - 1?, x_1 = 1? $

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, exponential-function

I need to find the general term for $ x_{n+1} = 3  x_n + n - 1, x_1 = 1. $

I don't know the proper methods and approaches to to solve this type of problem. I can see that $ 3^n$ is involved. I tried dividing and substracting $x_{n+1}$ by $x_n$ but that doesn't seem to reveal anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like for ODEs, linear equations with constant coefficients can be solved by adding:

- the general solution of homegenous equation $x_{n+1}-3x_n=0$ which you found already $x_n=\alpha3^n$
- and one particular solution when RHS=$n-1$

The form of the particular solution when RHS is a polynomial is also a polynomial, of same degree or elevated degree if the root $3^n$ is involved.

In our case since RHS does not contains $3^n$ we can search for a solution $an+b$

Thus $a(n+1)+b=3(an+b)+n-1\iff (2a+1)n+(2b-a-1)=0$ so $a=-\frac 12$ and $b=\frac 14$.

Thus $$x_n=\alpha\, 3^n-\frac n2+\frac 14$$

I let you calculate $\alpha$ so that initial condition $x_1=1$ is verified.

---

Suppose $x_n$ and $y_n$ are solutions, let subtract the equations and call $h_n=x_n-y_n$ :

We have $\require{cancel}x_{n+1}-y_{n+1}=(3x_n+\cancel{n-1})-(3y_n+\cancel{n-1})\iff h_{n+1}=3h_n$

So $h_n$ is solution of the homogenous equation $h_{n+1}=3h_n$.

This means that once you found one solution $y_n$ all the other solutions will be $x_n=y_n+h_n$.

Therefore you only need to find $1$ particular solution of the whole equation (in our case $-n/2+1/4$) and add $h_n=\alpha3^n$ to have them all.

Comment: $ α = 5/12 $. I don't know what ODE, linear equations with constant coefficients or homogenous equations are. $x_n = -n/2 + 1/4 $ seems to be true if $ x_1 = -1/4 $. Where did $ α 3^n $ come from?

Comment: Well $u_n=3u_{n-1}=3^2u_{n-2}=\cdots=3^nu_0$ just take $\alpha=u_0$ some unknown constant. You can have a look there for the theory https://brilliant.org/wiki/linear-recurrence-relations/

Comment: But why are you adding equations together? If I assume that $x_n = an + b$ I get $x_n  = -n/2 + 1/4$ which contradicts $x_1 = 1$.

Comment: What does it mean that $x_{n+1}−3x_n=0$ is a "homogenous equation"? Isn't it just a recursively defined sequence?

Comment: Homegenous means RHS=0. (i.e. we ignore the term $n-1$ because it does not contains references to $x_n$ sequence). Unfortunately it is not possible to explain all the lesson in comments. Basically when equation is linear the difference between two solutions is the solution of the homogenous equation, thus the adding.

Comment: So $x_{n+1} = 3 x_n + n - 1$ is a separate problem from $x_1 = 1$ and we are first finding all possible solutions to the first equation and then choosing the one solution that also matches the second equation? How did you know setting $x_n$ to $an + b$ would work to find one of the solutions?

Comment: Well this is the theory. If RHS = $P(n)r^n$ with $P$ polynomial then there exist a particular solution of the form $Q(n)r^n$ with $\deg(Q)=\deg(P)+m$ where $m$ is the multiplicity of the $r$ in the characteristic equation. (here $r=1$ and $m=0$). As  I said, there is a whole course behind all this.

Comment: Can you link to that? The page you linked does not talk about recurrences that contain functions unrelated to previous terms in the RHS, only recurrences where $x_n$ is a sum of previous terms multiplied by constants. Is $ x_{n+1} = 3x_n + n - 1$ a linear recurrence?